# Filtering Date In PHP DOM

Tags: php, parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

I wanna replace all date with a space from the fetched content using SIMPLE HTML PHP DOM PARSER (simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net). Here is the code:

```
include("simple_html_php_dom.php");
$html = file_get_html("http://freebacklinks.prijm.com"); //example.com
$result = "$html";
$result = preg_replace("/([1-9]|[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) [0-9]{4}/", " ", $result);
$result = preg_replace("/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) ([1-9]|[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) [0-9]{4}/", " ", $result);
echo $result;
```

So, here all date data like: `01 Jan 2004` or `Jan 01 2004` or `Dec 12 14` should be replaced by a space... But its not replacing those date with space.. Now what to do?
**Here is a example showing how it will work..** http://codepad.org/lAuHW565 **but why its not working in [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)**

Comment: I'm really confused with your references to DOM... You seem to be working with plain strings. What does `$result` look like?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario it will fetch full content from a page..

Comment: Here is a example showing how it will work.. http://codepad.org/lAuHW565

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to replace on a `SimpleHTML` object which is impossible (it's an object, not a string). What you should do is first get the HTML, then replace, and then turn it into `SimpleHTML` using the `str_get_html` function.

```
<?php
    include("simple_html_php_dom.php");

    //Start with getting the pure HTML and replacing in that (don't use SimpleHTMLPHP for this)
    $html = file_get_contents("http://freebacklinks.prijm.com"); //example.com
    $html= preg_replace("/([1-9]|[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\s+(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+[0-9]{4}/", " ", $html);
    $html = preg_replace("/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+([1-9]|[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\s+[0-9]{4}/", " ", $html);

    //Now create the $result variable:
    $result = str_get_html($html);
    echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: @MaxMuller You're right - my mistake - I read it as `file_get_contents` even though it was `file_get_html`. I changed the code to reflect your problem.

Comment: what is OP and can u check my new thread for this one :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380517/preg-replace-not-working thanks

Comment: @MaxMuller OP is "Original Post". Why doesn't this work for you? What does `$html` contain? Can you post an ACTUAL code (with a real source, not just an example domain)?

Comment: ok, thanks for your helpful hands :), suppose, can replace all those date by a space from this page http://prijom.com/posts/best-plugins-collection-for-drupal-7.php , i am trying to replace all date with a space while fetching content from this page..this code is not working for this page :( can you help?

Comment: @MaxMuller It is because, if you actually look at the source of the page, you'll find out that the dates are `Apr 14  2008`, `Sep 29  2011 ` etc, meaning they (for some reason) have put TWO spaces in between the date and the year. I've edited the regex to support multiple spaces (or tabs etc.) using `\s+` which means (space/tab/line break) repeated 1 or more times (this is what the `+` means.